# How to create and modify matrices and pass them into a function?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

I'm a MATLAB beginner and face quite an issue on a assignment. The goal of the assignement is to create music with functions the professor gave us. I managed to create a quite simple melody, but I would like to tackle something more complex: I wrote a simple melody in MIDI, opened it with a text editor and now I have a matrix of MIDI codes for the notes.

Now, the first step would be to translate those MIDI codes to frequencies:

I know that `freq = 440*power(2, (midicode-69)/12)`. I want to create a vector/matrix containing the MIDI codes passed through this formula (thus obtaining a matrix with the frequencies in it), and I can't seem to find the way to do it. The teacher's material is close to non-existent and my internet searches confuses me even more.

The next (and final?) step would be to pass those codes into the teachers function. It's called `newsound(f)`, and takes as an argument a frequency `f`. It then creates the sound by adding one by one the frequency components, and other utility stuff.

Now, what I need to pass into the `soundsc()` function of MATLAB is the result of `newsound(f)` of all the individual frequencies in a matrix called `S`. 
This is what I mean, and confuses me the most (I'm not really that great at maths either so yeah...)

Let's say `f(i)` is the vector/matrix containing the frequencies translated from MIDI. Then, `S` is a `1xn` sized matrix, 1 being the column, and `n` being the amount of frequencies: `S = (S1, S2, ..., Sn)` for `S1 = newsound(f(1))`, ..., `Sn = newsound(f(n))`.

I would really appreciate the help with how to play around these matrices!

Comment: Sorry, I meant that S1, S2, ..., SN are the components of S

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, it's possible to have multiple MIDI codes per "sound", and the amount of MIDI codes per "sound" can vary. So, a text file `midicodes.txt` containing the MIDI codes of your "sounds" may look like this:

```
60 61 69
62 64
63 68 69 72
```

The first step would be to read all the contents of that file:

```matlab
% Read MIDI codes from text file, get cell array of vectors with MIDI codes
fid = fopen('midicodes.txt');
midi_codes = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n')
midi_codes = cellfun(@(line) str2num(line), midi_codes{1}, 'UniformOutput', false)
fclose(fid);
```

The [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) will give us the whole lines as strings (or better: character arrays) from the text file (we need [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html) here, because of the varying lenghts of the MIDI code vectors):

```
midi_codes =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 60 61 69
    [2,1] = 62 64
    [3,1] = 63 68 69 72
  }
}
```

Then, we use [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) to convert each string (or better: character array) line into a numerical vector. To do this for each cell in our cell array, we use the [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) method.

```
midi_codes =
{
  [1,1] =
     60   61   69
  [2,1] =
     62   64
  [3,1] =
     63   68   69   72
}
```

Now, we set up an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) for the frequency calculation, and calculate the frequencies for all MIDI codes:

```matlab
% Anonymous function to convert (vectors of) MIDI codes to frequencies
freq = @(midicode) 440 * 2.^((midicode - 69) / 12);

% Calculate frequencies for all MIDI codes
frequencies = cellfun(freq, midi_codes, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Output:

```
frequencies =
{
  [1,1] =
     261.63   277.18   440.00
  [2,1] =
     293.66   329.63
  [3,1] =
     311.13   415.30   440.00   523.25
}
```

Now, we assume, that the `newsound` function actually calculates some "sound" from a frequency vector. As a mock-up, I created this `newsound.m` function file:

```matlab
function out = newsound(freq)
  out = sum(sin(freq));
end
```

We can create the actual "sounds" per MIDI code / frequency vector:

```matlab
% Generate sounds for all frequencies 
sounds = cellfun(@newsound, frequencies, 'UniformOutput', true)
```

Output:

```
sounds =
   0.070850
  -0.759869
   1.628095
```

And now:

```matlab
% Play sounds!?
soundsc(sounds);
```

If your text file looks differently, for example if you use another delimiter, you need to adapt the input reading part. If all of your MIDI code vectors have the same length, you can also use plain numerical arrays instead of cell arrays.

Hope that helps!

---

Disclaimer: Tested with Octave 5.1.0, but the syntax should be fully MATLAB compatible. If not, please report any error, and I will try to fix that as soon as possible.

---

**EDIT:** As requested in the comments, here's the full script:

```matlab
% Read MIDI codes from text file, get cell array of vectors with MIDI codes
fid = fopen('midicodes.txt');
midi_codes = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n')
midi_codes = cellfun(@(line) str2num(line), midi_codes{1}, 'UniformOutput', false)
fclose(fid);

% Anonymous function to convert (vectors of) MIDI codes to frequencies
freq = @(midicode) 440 * 2.^((midicode - 69) / 12);

% Calculate frequencies for all MIDI codes
frequencies = cellfun(freq, midi_codes, 'UniformOutput', false)

% Generate sounds for all frequencies 
sounds = cellfun(@newsound, frequencies, 'UniformOutput', true)

% Play sounds!?
%soundsc(sounds);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the help! Could you please link a full source? I'm getting a little bit lost...